# difficult series convergence question in calculus

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is the following series convergent?

$$\sum \dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^24^n}$$

Comment: Hint: $2n \choose n$ is the largest binomial coefficient of the form $2n \choose k$, so it exceeds the average binomial coefficient $2^{2n}/(2n+1)$.

Comment: To attack it from a different point of view, try rewriting $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^24^n}$ as $$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!2^n)^2}$$. Then the numerator becomes the product of the first $n$ odd Naturals, and the denominator the product of the fist $n$ even ones.

Comment: The main term behaves like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ by Stirling's inequality, so the series is trivially divergent. An interesting problem comes out if you replace the main term by its fourth power.

Answer (score 4):

Note that ${2n!\over (n!)^2}={2n\choose n}$ is a binomial coefficient. You know that binomial coefficients, ${k\choose m}$ add up to $2^k$. In particular, you know ${2n\choose n}< 2^{2n}$. But then you see that it being right in the middle means it is larger than all the others, in particular it is larger than the average, which is $\displaystyle{2^{2n}\over 2n+1}$.

So we see

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over 2n+ 1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {4^n\over (2n+1) 4^n}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(2n)!\over (n!)^2 4^n}$$

so the series diverges by comparison test.

Comment: Technically the average is $2^{2n} / (2n+1)$, but of course you are free to combine the first and last terms :).

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\frac{2n!}{(n!)^2 4^n}$. Note the ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1-\frac{0.5}{n+1}$.

Of course, the ratio test is inconclusive, but the above expression tells us something.

If $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$, then $b_n=\frac{b_0}{n}$ and the harmonic series diverges. Now observe that eventually $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}<\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. What does this tell you?